# Update the position of jQuery slider according to value programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have added a jQuery slider in my site. First time when a logged in customer measured the value from slider then slider value is stored in database and next time when he logged in, I want to show the slider value selected according to value stored in database for that logged in customer.

I updated the value of slider but the problem is position is not correct according to selected value of slider.

Please see the code below:

```
 $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
    if($customer->getId())
    {    

     $measurement_data = Mage::getModel("measurement/measurement")->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('customerid',$customer->getId())->getFirstItem();       
       $measurement_trouserwaist = $measurement_data->getTrouserWaist();

    }
    jQuery(function() {
        var select2 = jQuery( "#minbeds2" );
         var slider_set2 = jQuery( ".slider_set2" );

        var slider = jQuery( "<div style='' id='slider3'></div>" ).insertAfter(slider_set2 ).slider({
          min: 1,
          max: 8,
          range: "min",
         // value: select2[ 0 ].selectedIndex + 1,
          value: select2[ 0 ].selectedIndex + <?php echo ($measurement_trouserwaist)?$measurement_trouserwaist:'1';?>,
          slide: function( event, ui ) {


            jQuery("#minbeds3")[0].selectedIndex = ui.value - 1;
            //select[ 0 ].selectedIndex = ui.value - 1;
            jQuery('.value6').html(ui.value + 29);
            jQuery("#f").css("display", "block");
             jQuery("#measure_waist").val(ui.value + 29 + "inch");
          }
        });

        //jQuery( ".ui-slider-handle" ).html(jQuery( ".select" ).html());
        min=30;
        max= 37;

            var array = [];

        for (var i = min; i <= max; i++) {
            array.push(i);
        }

            //Create and append select list
            var selectList2 = document.createElement("select");
            selectList2.setAttribute("id", "minbeds3");
            selectList2.setAttribute("name", "minbeds3");
            selectList2.setAttribute("class", "minbeds3");
            //document.getElementsByClassName("ui-slider-handle").appendChild(selectList);
            jQuery( "#slider3 .ui-slider-handle" ).html(selectList2);
            //Create and append the options
            for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                var option2 = document.createElement("option");
                option2.setAttribute("value", array[i]);
         if(array[i]=='<?php echo ($measurement_trouserwaist)?$measurement_trouserwaist:'1';?>'){
                    option2.setAttribute("selected", 'selected'); 

                    }  
                option2.text = array[i];
                selectList2.appendChild(option2);
                  document.getElementById("minbeds3").appendChild(option2);

            }

         jQuery( "#minbeds3" ).change(function() {
          slider.slider( "value", this.selectedIndex + 1 );
          jQuery('.value6').html(this.selectedIndex + 30);
          jQuery("#f").css("display", "block"); 
          jQuery("#measure_waist").val(this.selectedIndex + 30 + "inch");
        });

      });
```

How to update the position according to the value, though I got the updated value from database but according to the value position is not updating.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch the value out the database, using a server-side programming language like PHP. Then return that value on a page, and get it with AJAX.

So for example:

## fetch.php

```
<?php
    $query = "SELECT value FROM table WHERE userid = " . $_GET['userid'];
    $run = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    $fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($run);

    echo $fetch['userid'];
?>
```

## jQuery

```
$.get("fetch.php?userid=" + userid, function(data){
    $("#slider").slider("value", data);
});
```

This will work, replace #slider with your own slider, the query for your own query and the variable userid, with however you want you want to use in your `WHERE` part.

Comment: No, I can't use other slider because there are other functionality as well which is very useful for me if you want to help then help from my given code which is implemented in magento site

Comment: What do you mean "other slider"?

Comment: I already fetched the data from database and it is shown in slider as well but the problem is slider value is updating but its position doesnot.please see the starting 5 lines for fetching data from database